# automated selection by attributes and location within another Layer

Tags: qgis, select-by-attribute, qgis-modeler

I have two Polygon Layers. Layer A are Districts of a City and Layer B are Blocks of a City. Currently i'm working with QGIS 2.6.1 and i don't have  access to any other GIS.

What i'm trying to do is: select Blocks in Layer B within (contain) a specific District in Layer A. I'm already able to select a certain District in Layer A by using "select by Attributes" followed by "select by Location" with Layer B by checking the "current selection" Option.

These Kind of Operation i've to do quite often and i'm looking for a way now where i can build a automated process with the "graphical modeler". So far the single steps are working but i'm not able to choose a specific Field and Value (*District*; *Distict Name*) i.e. a dropdown menue of Layer A. So even with that Modeler i've to fill out the Field and Value for each Process.

Is there any Way for an automated Process?

Answer (score 1):

There is a model builder equivalent in QGIS 
 [Tutorial](http://www.digital-geography.com/creating-models-qgis/#.VbtCnPntla8)

While editing the builder save regularly, it isn't the most stable tool in the world =)

Comment: thanks Juls. Like i said, im already looking for a way with the *graphical modeler* in QGIS. I just haven't found a way to select the Parameters after i've bulid it. When i run the model i want to choose which Layer, Column an Value. Like Layer _Districts_ Column _District Name_ Name _Name_.

Comment: Ah my bad. I havent had any luck to make the builder take user input... Your best bet will probably be in using pyqgis through the console